# Static page plugin - List with all pages url as a custom page field

Tags: octobercms

I'm using static page plugin. I need a way to get from a custom field all the pages of the octobercms. I don't care how this will be done (official page url selector - dropdown list ...), I want only to be user friendly so can be used from a client.

[There is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738734/static-page-dropdown-within-static-page-in-octobercms/47746926#47746926) but it works only with repeater. If I use it with one other field `{variable name="page" label="Page" type="dropdown"}{/variable}` I got an error:

```
get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given
```

Comment: I have checked and error is occurring, its weekend so little busy with family, will surely solve this tomorrow and post solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow! this question really tighten my brain's nuts and bolts,

> Thanks for the Question, I really enjoyed it to solve.

As if we use normal variable outside of the repeater October field parse will treat it as name as `viewBag[page]` and it is not working with `fieldParser` and `fieldOptions` getter methods. (its little technical so I would like to skip this and jump to real solution)

> any how at last I found little hack/kind of extension/functionality (extensive nature of October Cms) and use it

you need any plugin so you can write extension code inside `boot` method.

```
public function boot() {
    $alias = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance()
              ->alias('MyPluginOptionAlias','October\\Demo\\plugin');
}
```

here you can correct `alias-name` and `namespace` we are making our plugin object globally available using this `alias` **(MyPluginOptionAlias)**

and inside `plugin.php` we add two `static` methods so we can access them later, this will be just `logic` of getting `page-list` and return it as an array.

```
public static function getPageOptions() {

    // different lists // or even you can merge them
    $result =  self::getTypeInfo('cms-page');
    // $result =  self::getTypeInfo('static-page');
    // $result =  self::getTypeInfo('blog-post');
    return $result['references'];
}


public static function getTypeInfo($type)
{
    $result = [];
    $apiResult = \Event::fire('pages.menuitem.getTypeInfo', [$type]);

    if (is_array($apiResult)) {
        foreach ($apiResult as $typeInfo) {
            if (!is_array($typeInfo)) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($typeInfo as $name => $value) {
                if ($name == 'cmsPages') {
                    $cmsPages = [];

                    foreach ($value as $page) {
                        $baseName = $page->getBaseFileName();
                        $pos = strrpos($baseName, '/');

                        $dir = $pos !== false ? substr($baseName, 0, $pos).' / ' : null;
                        $cmsPages[$baseName] = strlen($page->title)
                            ? $dir.$page->title
                            : $baseName;
                    }

                    $value = $cmsPages;
                }

                $result[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

> **Now the main thing**

```
{variable name="page" label="Page" type="dropdown" options="MyPluginOptionAlias|getPageOptions" tab="link"}{/variable}
```

you define **options** `exactly` like this **`MyPluginOptionAlias|getPageOptions`**

Logic here is that now it will fetch option list from our `MyPluginOptionAlias` instance's **`method: getPageOptions`**

> what ever `array` you return from it will be listed as options for this drop-down.

please comment if it creates any issue, we will correct it.