# Vue.js dynamic OctoberCMS menu with JSON data?

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-router, octobercms

I'd like to know how is it possible with vue.js to have a router with dynamic routes, instead of static ones, to render a menu based on the October Static Menu items and Pages ?

Thanks for help.

In October backend, I used regular MDBootstrap with the following partial to render a dynamic menu based on Static Pages and Menus :

```
    <!-- Navbar Logo -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <!-- Collapse button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Collapsible content -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        {% if staticMenu.menuItems %}
        {% set items = staticMenu.menuItems %}
        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            {% for item in items %}
                <li class="nav-item {{ item.isActive or item.isChildActive ? 'active' : '' }}
                    {{ item.items ? 'dropdown btn-group' : '' }}"
                >
                    <a class="nav-link {% if item.items %}dropdown-toggle {% endif %}"
                            {% if item.items %} id="dropdownMenu{{ item.title|replace({' ':'-'}) }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"{% endif %}
                       href="{{ item.url }}"
                    >
                        {{ item.title }}

                        {% if item.items %}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>{% endif %}
                    </a>

                    {% if item.items %} <!-- Sous-menu -->
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary"
                            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu{{ item.title|replace({' ':'-'}) }}">
                            {% for child in item.items %}
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
        <!-- Links -->
    </div>
    <!-- Collapsible content -->

    <!-- Search form -->
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-333" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-primary"
          aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-333">
          <a class="dropdown-item {{ this.page.baseFileName == 'login' ? 'active' : '' }}" href="{{ 'login'|page }}">
            {% if not user %}
                Login
            {% else %}
                My profile
            {% endif %}
          </a>
          {% if user %}
          <a class="dropdown-item" data-request="onLogout" data-request-data="redirect: '/logout'">Sign out</a>
          {% endif %}
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
<!--/.Navbar-->
```

Items are properly rendered and modified if I change backend items.

Now I'd like to switch my frontend to a Vue.js app with MDB Vue.

In samples routes are always statics and in nice Watch+Learn Rentacar app also (https://watch-learn.com/creating-rent-car-app-vue-and-october/creating-rentacar-app-with-vue-and-october-homepage-ui)

I made a menu component with the following samples (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/navigation/navbar). Now that it is rendered, I'm wondering how in my vue component I could parse my backend items like in Twig ???

The menu component source (static) is :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <mdb-navbar dark color="primary" name="Your Logo" href="#">
      <mdb-navbar-toggler>
        <mdb-navbar-nav>
          <mdb-nav-item to="/navigation/navigation-v1">Version 1</mdb-nav-item>
          <mdb-nav-item to="/navigation/navigation-v2" active>Version 2</mdb-nav-item>
          <mdb-nav-item to="/navigation/navigation-v3">Version 3</mdb-nav-item>
          <mdb-nav-item to="/navigation/navigation-v4">Version 4</mdb-nav-item>
          <!-- mdbDropdown -->
          <mdb-dropdown tag="li" class="nav-item">
            <mdb-dropdown-toggle slot="toggle" tag="a" navLink color="primary" waves-fixed>Dropdown</mdb-dropdown-toggle>
            <mdb-dropdown-menu>
              <mdb-dropdown-item>Action</mdb-dropdown-item>
              <mdb-dropdown-item>Another action</mdb-dropdown-item>
              <mdb-dropdown-item>Something else here</mdb-dropdown-item>
            </mdb-dropdown-menu>
          </mdb-dropdown>
        </mdb-navbar-nav>
        <!-- Search form -->
        <form>
          <mdb-input type="text" class="text-white" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" label navInput waves waves-fixed/>
        </form>
      </mdb-navbar-toggler>
    </mdb-navbar>
    <!--/.Navbar-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mdbNavbar, mdbNavItem, mdbNavbarNav, mdbNavbarToggler, mdbDropdown, mdbDropdownItem, mdbDropdownMenu, mdbDropdownToggle, mdbInput } from 'mdbvue';

export default {
  name: 'NavigationPage',
  components: {
    mdbNavbar,
    mdbNavItem,
    mdbNavbarNav,
    mdbNavbarToggler,
    mdbDropdown,
    mdbDropdownItem,
    mdbDropdownMenu,
    mdbDropdownToggle,
    mdbInput
  },
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById("main-navbar").style.height = '60px';
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.getElementById("main-navbar").style.height = null;
  }
};
</script>
```

## Thanks for clues !

Well, I now made some progress to the solution ! In my Vue.js app, I would like to get JSON data with the menu levels.
Based on this post ([How to get static page dropdown in OctoberCMS with get page tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477068/how-to-get-static-page-dropdown-in-octobercms-with-get-page-tree)) in my October plugin, I'm able to create a route which sends the data to Vue.js.

But when I do :

```
  $theme = \Cms\Classes\Theme::getEditTheme();
  $pageList = new \RainLab\Pages\Classes\PageList($theme);
  $treePageList = $pageList->getPageTree(true);
  return $treePageList;
```

I get a structure with too much details.
How could I simplify it to have only a JSON data with the title and the url of my multilevel menu ?
I would like to obtain something like :

```
  "Sub pages"   "sub-pages"         +
        "Child One"     "child-1"
        "Child Two"     "child-2"
        "Child Three"   "child-3"
        "Child Four"    "child-4"           +
            "Sub Child" "sub-child"
  "Forms"       "forms"     +
        "Form Contact"      "form-contact"
  "test"        "test"
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Share the code on what you are doing now. Its hard to make suggestions if we don't know your website infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I published my code.

Comment: /navigation/:navigationId

Comment: @Estradiaz : could you please be more explicit ? Thanks

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Thanks, I'm diving into Vue routes, but it's the client side...
I'm still searching also help on the October side... How could I query the menu structure like with Twig ?